I am finding it difficult to access my files in the component folder for a React App I am building on Visual Studio code
Error Message:
The document “MainComponent.js” could not be opened. Your device couldn’t connect to the server. There may be a problem with the server or network.
Note:

I have internet connection and can do other things with my macbook.
I have been working on this project, just resumed this morning and having this error.
I created the MainComponent.css file this morning and I can access it only.

I have closed Visual Studio and re-opened.
I checked my internet connection.
I have checked if the files still exist in the project folder and it does.
I have run this command 'touch MainComponent.js' in my terminal but none have seemed to work.

Could it be that the file permissions have be tampered with accidentally?
To ensure that the file permissions for MainComponent.js allow read and write access:

Open the Terminal and navigate to the project directory.
Run the following command to check permissions:

ls -l MainComponent.js


If the permissions need to be adjusted, you can modify them using:

chmod 644 MainComponent.js

Otherwise if its not too troublesome, perhaps try opening MainComponent.js in another text editor (atom / notepad++ etc) and try copying, and pasting into a new js file?

I tried all of that and it was blank in a different editor as well. Did a quick system reboot and that fixed my problem.
Thanks though.
